# Which OpAmp is the best option for a high speed peak/envelope detector?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I know there are a bunch of questions about peak detectors, but I couldn't find an answer to my problem in them. I would like to design a peak detector (or envelope detector, I don't understand the difference between them). Ideally, something like this

[image]

Results would look like this

[image]

As you can see, the input signal is rather fast (around 15 MHz) and I want to detect abrupt changes in a few cycles. However, since the diode I place will have a dropout somewhere between 0.5 V and 1 V, I want to use a "precision diode" configuration with an OpAmp.

I have tried a bunch of Analog Devices' OpAmps included in LTSpice but none of them worked correctly. For instance, I have run a simulation with the ADA4807-4:

[image]

I set the frequency in the kHz range, as suggested by @Bimpelrekkie. Results are shown below
[image]

The current through the capacitor is not supplied by the diode (always off) but through the negative pin of the OpAmp.

When I find an OpAmp with enough GBW and slew-rate, input current ruins the circuit. Could you recommend me an OpAmp for this application? Or maybe some suggestion to the circuit?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) *Or maybe some suggestion to the circuit?* Show us the circuit you used to test those opamps. 2) Did you try your cicruit with a much slower signal, like 15 kHz i.s.o. 15 MHz? Then bandwidth and slewrate of the opamp should matter much less so then you can at least know if your circuit can even work. 3) envelope detector or peak detector are indeed more or less the same thing.

Comment: If the issue with the diode is its biasing voltage, perhaps you could DC bias then diode (which will also add DC bias to the capacitor past the diode), and then apply the fast signal through a coupling capacitor to your envelope detector. IMHO you only need a buffer like an Emitter follower at the output of the envelope detector, and could do without an OP Amp

Comment: If frequency is constant, use a fast multiplier with signal quadrature.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I edited the question for answering you. I see a problem with input impedance of the OpAmp.

Comment: Any spec for the phase stability of the input signal? Does the input amplitude fade to zero or does it stay detectable even at weakest? Allowed startup synchronization delay (=allowed time to proper detection functionality when the 15MHz signal is switched on)? What kind of noise there is and how much it must be rejected? What's the actual system level design goal that you think to become solved by sending something as amplitude changes at 15 Mhz and finding the wanted 15 MHz amplitude detector circuit (=just to give a possibility to suggest other transmission principle)?

Comment: *I see a problem with input impedance of the OpAmp* **WHY?** I think the input impedance will be a complete non-issue. So explain why you think it is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Some **Log-Log-amplifiers** provide fast response of envelopes. The amplitude of their *[RSSI output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4Dv5.png)* (received signal strength indicator) has a log response rather than linear - may not be what you want. The detector accepts input signals over a dynamic range of about 90 dB. A diode peak detector can't do that well.
These single-chip receivers accept RF up to nearly 1 GHz (14 MHz is easy) and add very little noise:

[image: RSSI output AD8306]

<sub>Image source: [AD8306 datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8306.pdf)</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your response. Seems quite interesting but I think I might be adding extra complexity to a seemingly simple endeavor. I only want to obtain the peak amplitude of a ~MHz with little precision (5 bits over a range of 4 V would be just fine).

Answer (score 1):

Here a simple alternative, but non linear ...

[image]

with larger pulse

[image]

For the fun, a synchronized "sampling peak demodulator", tested on simple wave @ 1MHz.

[image]

And here @ 1MHz , the resulting demodulation

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It also seems interesting but I might be adding too much extra complexity.